# Query Class properties by the interface they implemented

Tags: c#, linq

I have something like this

```
public class Dto
{
    public A[] As { get; set; }
    public B[] Bs { get; set; }
    public C[] Cs { get; set; }
}
public class A:IName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Years { get; set; }
}
public class B : IName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public class C : ISurename
{
    public string Surename { get; set; }
}
public interface IName
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}
public interface ISurename
{
   String Surename { get; set; }
}
```

Can i run a Linq query on the Dto class that will return to me list of IName in a way it will be all 'As' and 'Bs' Names values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use:

```
IEnumerable<IName> result = myDto.As.Concat(myDto.Bs);
```